# Magento 1.5.1.0 images folder

Tags: magento

Any help on getting the images folder of magento 1.5.1.0 ?
Is it located in media/catalog/product ?
Thanks.

Comment: upload an image and see where it is placed ? 1.5.1.0 can hold images in database also so you need to check your config for that also

Comment: Products images are stored in /media/catalog/.

Comment: They are also dispersed (file.jpg will go in something like /f/i/file.jpg)

Comment: @Mathew: yeah. whats the logic it uses? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are dispersed, e.g. file.jpg will go to /media/catalog/product/f/i/file.jpg - the first sub-directory is the first letter of the product image, the second directory is the second letter of the product image.

To download/upload the images in the 'easiest' way depends on whether you have shell access. If uploading the images again you might want to use the dataflow profiles as they will manage dispersion for you.